# emplace_front in a std::multimap

Tags: c++, multimap

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap),

> The order of the key-value pairs whose keys compare equivalent is the
> order of insertion and does not change.

That's great. I need that guarantee. However, I also sometime need to insert a value at the beginning of the list, for a given key. I could erase all the nodes that match the given key, insert my new node, and reinsert all the previous nodes, but...is there a better way?

Comment: `std::multilmap` does not support `emplace_front`.  AFAIK, there isn't a way for you to decide where the element goes besides providing a hint that may be used.

Comment: Instead of a `multimap` you could use a `std::map<key_type, std::vector<value_type>>` and then you can have control on how the objects are ordered for any key.

Comment: There is no guarantee on your requirement, I guess your safest bet would be to use a `std::map<K, std::vector<T>>` to have the flexibility you need.

Comment: Just for clarity when using std::map<key_type, std::vector<value_type>> if key_type is a non standard type you might have to provide a specialized version of Compare as template parameter too